Renderでのデプロイ失敗原因がわからない
この度railsにて個人アプリ開発するにあたりRenderでのデプロイをしようと試みています。
同じ箇所で永遠にループし，最後は止まってしまう現象が起きており原因がわからないため
何卒お力添えいただけると幸いです。
以下ログが何度か繰り返され途中でデプロイが止まってしまいます。
試したこと:

自動保存を止めた
--watch の記載の削除

海外サイト含め調べたのですが，なかなか答えがわからず...教えて頂けたら幸いです。
1 gem installed
13:30:21 web.1  | started with pid 18
13:30:21 js.1   | started with pid 19
13:30:21 css.1  | started with pid 23
13:30:25 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.19
13:30:25 css.1  | yarn run v1.22.19
13:30:26 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets
13:30:26 css.1  | $ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --minify
13:30:27 js.1   | 
13:30:27 js.1   |   app/assets/builds/application.js      261.9kb
13:30:27 js.1   |   app/assets/builds/application.js.map  481.2kb
13:30:27 js.1   | 
13:30:28 js.1   | Done in 3.00s.
13:30:28 js.1   | exited with code 0
13:30:28 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
13:30:28 web.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
13:30:29 css.1  | exited with code 1
Installing foreman...
Successfully installed foreman-0.87.2

package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.2",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^8.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "daisyui": "^4.8.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.20.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --minify",
    "dev": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets"
  }
}


ローカル環境で試すとどうなりますか？ Render.com でデプロイした場合の固有の問題なのかを切り分ける必要があると思います。 Render.com はフリープランだと使えるリソース (メモリ) が限られているようなので、その辺りが怪しい気もします。
